# Map object in array of objects react-image-gallery problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, mapping

I want to use react-image-gallery when structure looks like this:

```
let images = [{original: '1.jpg', thumbnail: '1.jpg'}, {original: '2.jpg', thumbnail: '2.jpg'}, ... ];

<ImageGallery items={images}/>
```

In my case:

```
const somObj = {name: 'some-name', photos: ['/somObj/1.jpg', '/somObj/2.jpg', ...]};
```

I tried to map like this:

```
<ImageGallery items={[
somObj.map(item=> ({ original: item, thumbnail: item }) )
]}/>
```

I've also tried it differently, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You are mapping at the wrong level

You can only use map on an array so go inside your object and into the photo's array. You also don't need the array brackets around the map since map returns an array already.

```
<ImageGallery items={somObj.photos.map(item => ({ original: item, thumbnail: item }))}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

your `someObj` is not an array, array is `photos` inside `someObj`:

```
<ImageGallery items={[
somObj.photos.map(item=> { return {original: item, thumbnail: item }})
]}/>
```